# Console application consuming wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, console, asp.net-4.0

I have a c# asp.net web application/projct which is working well. Later I added a wcf service as new item to this proj. Then I add a new simple Console application to this solution to consume the wcf. It works fine in my local. (My local server name is A. Using
[http://A/MyProjName/wcfSendRpt.svc] OR [http://localhost/MyProjName/wcfSendRpt.svc] both Okay). 
Then I published my web application( with the wcf service) to live server B. (B just host this only web-application. ) Both [http://B/wcfSendRpt.svc] OR [http://localhost/wcfSendRpt.svc] works fine.
Then I deployed my Console application to server B. ( I just copied the exe and config files to sever B). I changed the endpoint address in config file from [http://A/MyProjName/wcfSendRpt.svc] to [http://B/wcfSendRpt.svc] like below

```
<endpoint address="http://B/wcfSendRpt.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IwcfSendRpt"
          contract="nsSendRpt.IwcfSendRpt" name="BasicHttpBinding_IwcfSendRpt" />
```

But it doesn't work. the error from event log is like below:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.Ex
ceptionDetail]: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See th
e inner exception for details.

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
 reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverte
r faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRunt
ime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean on
eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim
eout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage req
Msg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgDa
ta, Int32 type)
   at CAScheduledService.nsSendRpt.IwcfSendRpt.SendRpt(String statementdate)
   at CAScheduledService.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

My console application is very simple: the code is like below

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            nsSendRpt.IwcfSendRptClient ss = new IwcfSendRptClient();
            string a = ss.SendRpt(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            ss.Close();
        }
    }
```

I need your help to solve this. And I am pretty new in wcf. Is this wcf service in my web application is restful?

Comment: Internal error means what it says. The problem was internal to the service. Check in the Windows Event Log, or else turn on [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx) to see what exception is being thrown by the service.

Comment: After all, I figured it out. Thanks a lot John. The problem is that there is table's column name different from the live one. But without tracing I can't find the problem. So I add this to config file
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true" > <listeners><add name="xml"/></listeners>
      </source>
      ......
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Error.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>